# Crystal Reports 2013: Are examples missing from the help file?

Tags: crystal-reports

I just upgraded to Crystal Reports 2013 and I repeatedly find topics in the help file that seem unfinished.  One example is "subtotaling grouped data" in the index shows "In this example you will subtotal Last Year's Sales by Country".  That's it!  No example.  No link.

Am I missing something from my installation or is this all that SAP provides?

Thanks.

Comment: The example is on the next page, just hit the right-arrow. In my copy (CR 2011), the page you reference ends with: "In this section: To subtotal data" and is itself a link to the next page.

Comment: Thanks Ryan.  I have no navigation arrows.  I tried the arrow keys, Page Up/Down, and various key chords that work in other programs but none of my actions would change the page or show more content.